# What is the "Parse error in pattern" in my Credit Card Validation written in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The goal is to validate a list of numbers (credit card number for example ) to first initiate it, reverse it, and then double it, and that would give the sum. Then it would tell if it is valid or in-valid. I have written the code but it wont compile right. It keeps saying this: test.hs:22:1: Parse error in pattern: sumNum. 
Here is my code:

```
main = do
toDigits    :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]

toDigitsRev n
        where
         n <= 0 = []
         otherwise = n `mod` 10 : toDigitsRev (n `div` 10)

toDigits = reverse . toDigitsRev

double :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

double [] = []
double (x:[]) = [x]
double (x:y:zs) = x : (2 * y) : double zs
doubleRev = reverse . double . reverse

sumNum :: [Integer] -> Integer 

sumNum [] = 0
sumNum (x:xs)
  x < 10 = x + sumNum xs
  otherwise = (x `mod` 10) + (x `div` 10) + sum xs

validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate n = (mod (sumNum (doubleRev (toDigits n))) 10) == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the guard bars:

```
sumNum (x:xs)
    | x < 10 = ...
    | otherwise = ...
```

Without the pipe characters, the compiler sees it as `sumNum (x:xs) x < 10 = x + sumNum xs`, which doesn't make sense as a pattern, since it seems to suggest you have 3 more arguments, namely `x`, `<` and `10`, although `<` does not make sense as a name by itself.  Alternatively you could just skip the guard altogether, since

```
> map (`mod` 10) [0..9] == [0..9]
True
> map (`div` 10) [0..9] == replicate 10 0
True
```

So all you save is a little efficiency.  Since you're working with very small inputs you don't really need to worry about this, so you could just use `` sumNum [] = 0; sumNum (x:xs) = (x `mod` 10) + (x `div` 10) + sum xs ``, or more simply `` sumNum = sum . map (\x -> (x `mod` 10) + (x `div` 10)) ``.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i just answered my own question again with a error that i got just by adding the guard bars.

Comment: & also i am running on linux through terminal so i am wondering when it says prelude> what am i suppose to type in to initiate the number i wish to plug in